# Getting 500 error for Msmdpump.dll OLAP data pump

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis-7, ssas

I am trying to connect to my SSAS through localhost by following the below link
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-infrastructure-cognos_specific-page670/

I followed all the steps and was unsuccessful in connecting. It is giving me Internal server (500) error.

Comment: You should follow the Microsoft docs for setting up the SSAS data pump: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0

Comment: Tried the same but no use.Still i am getting the same error.